# QGraphicsPolygonItem scale from top left

Tags: c++, qt, scaling, qgraphicsitem

I have one question for all, regarding QGraphicsPolygonItem scaling.

I have polygon (inside QGraphicsPolygonItem):

```
QPolygonF p1; 
p1 << QPointF(-4, 32) << QPointF(-4, -32) << QPointF(4, -32) << QPointF(4, 32);
//or
//p1 << QPointF(0, 0) << QPointF(8, 0) << QPointF(8, 64) << QPointF(0, 64);
//whatever, they both doesn't work correctly.
```

Then, I try to scale it ( setScale(2) ), and Polygon start to scale from center point, not from top, left. I have read documentation about Qt scaling and origin points but no effect.
For testing purpose, I have change polygon to rectangle - scale working correctly.

How to scale polygon from top, left ?

No scale ( polygon red, rectangle black ):
[image: setScale(1)]
<sub>(source: [sources.ru](http://forum.sources.ru/uploads/post-10-1323844540-0.png))</sub>

With scale x2:
[image: setScale(2)]
<sub>(source: [sources.ru](http://forum.sources.ru/uploads/post-10-1323844540-1.png))</sub>

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the the [`setTransformOriginPoint`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#setTransformOriginPoint) :

> Sets the origin point for the transformation in item coordinates.

Comment: setTransformOriginPoint doesn't solve this problem, because it's change only start point for transformation (center to top, left). As you can see on picture 2 (Scale x2) problem is in polygon overlapping after scaling. To prevent this need to use translate (probably). I need after scaling:  1. Scale polygon, 2. scale it's X,Y position (like for black rectangle on Picture 2 ).